# SQL Error:# 1064 when creating function in plsql using mysql

Tags: mysql, function

Here is my plsql code

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculate_hours(mon varchar(20),years INT,i INT)
RETURNS varchar(10)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE col1 varchar(10);
DECLARE col2 varchar(10);
DECLARE str1 varchar(30);
DECLARE str2 varchar(30);
SET str1='CHR_MORNING'+i;
SET str2='CHR_EVENING'+i;
SELECT str1 ,str2   FROM att_t_register WHERE CHR_MONTH=mon AND INT_YEAR=years;
SET col1=str1;
SET col2=str2;
IF(col1='SUN' && col2='SUN') THEN
RETURN 'S';
ELSE IF(col1='HOL' && col2='HOL') THEN
RETURN 'H';
ELSE IF(col1='LEA' && col2='LEA') THEN
RETURN 'L';
ELSE IF(col1='ABS' && col2='ABS') THEN
RETURN '-';
ELSE IF(col1='NA' && col2='NA') THEN
RETURN '-';
END IF;
RETURN '8';
END;
```

When I was running this I got error like..

**SQL EXECUTION ERROR # 1064. RESPONSE FROM DATA BASE 
You have an error in your sql syntax ; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 26**

please help me where I did mistake.

Comment: I don't see 26 lines here.

Comment: Would you please be so nice and tell us, what your code should do? It's a MySQL error. You seem to try to execute a dynamically generated sql statement. That's not the way to do it. You've got to preprare it and then execute it. The way to look into results of such a statement is wrong too.

Comment: Thank you.What mistake I did in code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a function for this, you need a stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name(IN col_number1 INT, IN col_number2 INT)
BEGIN
SET @col1 := CONCAT('CHR_MORNING', col_number1);
SET @col2 := CONCAT('CHR_EVENING', col_number2);

SET @sql := CONCAT('
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ', @col1, '="SUN" && ', @col2, '="SUN" THEN "S"
WHEN (', @col1, '="HOL" && ', @col2, '="HOL") THEN "H"
WHEN (', @col1, '="LEA" && ', @col2, '="LEA") THEN "L"
WHEN (', @col1, '="ABS" && ', @col2, '="ABS") THEN "-"
WHEN (', @col1, '="NA" && ', @col2, '="NA") THEN "-"
ELSE "8"
END AS whatever_you_want_to_name_your_column
FROM att_t_register WHERE CHR_MONTH = "jan" AND INT_YEAR = 2014;
');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you'd execute it with

```
CALL proc_name(1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I mention str1 as CONCAT('CHR_MORNING',@i), str2 as CONCAT('CHR_EVENING',@i) in select query. I tried I did not get. Please help me.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? What are you trying to do? In your code you do `SET str1='CHR_MORNING'+i;`. MySQL tries to convert text to number, since you're adding `i` which is declared as integer. Text converted to numbers will always be `0` unless it begins with a number. Your variable `str` will therefore always be `i`. When using `CONCAT()` you put strings (and numbers) together and get a string back. Without knowing what you want to do, I'd say that what you tried should be correct.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have table att_t_register which is having fields CHR_MORNING1,CHR_EVENING1,CHR_MORNING2,CHR_EVENING2,...CHR_MORNING31,CHR_EVENING31,CHR_MONTH,INT_YEAR. I have to calculate no of hours based on values of that column according to month and year. I have to generate report for those values using jasper reports. Please help me.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I call in select statement. Is it possible to call procedure in select query? Because in jasper reports used select query to generate report based on retrieving columns. I am a fresher and beginner please help me.

Comment: It's not possible in `select` statement and there's no other way to do it in MySQL. Don't know how to call it with jasper reports, but it would be really strange if this weren't possible. Since this is a whole other topic, you'd have to create another question here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Oh, and the usual way to say thanks here on SO is to accept the answer and/or upvote if the problem has been solved.

Comment: how to call this procedure from function? Is it possible to call procedure from function I tried but I got error. please help me.

Comment: Need to know what you actually tried and what's the error message.

Comment: I called procedure in function like CREATE FUNCTION my_fun(col1 INT, col2 varchar(20),col3 INT) RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN(CAL proc_name1(col1,col1,col2,col3););

Comment: I got SQL Error:1064 at 'TABLE AS RETURN(CAL proc_nam1(col1,col1,col2,col3))'

Comment: You can't return a table, write the result into a (temporary) table and read it from there.