# How to write pl/sql or equivalent of it, in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, plsql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure` ()
declare v int;
BEGIN

v := 10;

dbms_output.put_line(v);

END
```

Here I was writing this simple code in create procedure portion and getting error in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: ....what error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Error:# 1064 when creating function in plsql using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077106/sql-error-1064-when-creating-function-in-plsql-using-mysql)

Comment: I'm confused as far as I know mysql workbench only works with mysql but the code looks like plsql. Are you trying to convert  plsql to mysql (dbms_output.put_line does not exist in mysql) or are you simply using the wrong tool (maybe you should be using sql developer for oracle)

Comment: It's not valid PL/SQL either.

Comment: please suggest the MySQL alternative for dbms_output.put_line in MySQL. Also please suggest the equivalent of pl/sql in MySQL workbench

Comment: Mysql does not have a procedural language just MySql's version of sql. Can you tell us what is it you are trying to do with dbms_output.put_line?

Comment: I want to print the value in the console

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create a stored procedure in `MySQL` from `Workbench`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedure
(IN colValue CHAR(20))
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MyTable(MyColumn) VALUES(colValue);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

You can read more about it in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html).

To execute the procedure: `CALL MyStoredProcedure(<some_value>);`

Stored procedures were introduced in `MySQL 5` so be sure to be running that version.

Why do we need to temporarily change the `DELIMITER`?

From the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html):

> By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement
>   delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause
>   mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server. To
>   redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command.